# How to share interactive video on twitter?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, twitter, html5-video

I have a simple html5 interactive video, you can see it here live

[live interactive video](https://meed.audiencevideo.com/onlyvideo.html)

I want something like this, the first tweet here

[retube twitter](https://twitter.com/retubetv)

I tried something like this

```
 <li><a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=Twitter
                        Text&amp;url=me id="tweet-button" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"
                        src="https://meed.audiencevideo.com/onlyvideo.html"
                        style="width:110px; height:200px;"></iframe>" title="Share on
                        Twitter" target="_blank" id="twitterbtn" class="share-btn btn
                        btn-twitter">
                        <img src="images/twitter.png">
                    </a>
        </li>
```

What do I need to do to get what I want?

Is it possible to achieve what I want?

Comment: No, Twitter does not support interactive videos, either posted directly, or if they are included in a player card.

Comment: No , your wrong it does, and I managed to solve the problem

Comment: can you provide an example? A Tweet that has this interactive video?